# How to add iOS native libraries and use it on nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to add an iOS native library, [Jumio](https://github.com/Jumio/mobile-sdk-ios), to my nativescript project. I follow [nativescript document](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/cocoapods) instruction. as it said, I did these steps:

1- Create cli project:

```
tns create MYCocoaPodsApp
cd MYCocoaPodsApp
tns platform add ios
```

2- Wrap the Library as NativeScript Plugin

```
cd ..
mkdir my-plugin
cd my-plugin
```

3- Create a package.json inside of `my-plugin` with the following content

```
{
  "name": "my-plugin",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "nativescript": {
    "platforms": {
      "ios": "1.3.0"
    }
  }
}
```

4- Create a Podfile inside of `my-plugin/platforms/ios/Podfile` file with following content (I copied it from [the native library document](https://github.com/Jumio/mobile-sdk-ios/blob/master/docs/integration_netverify-fastfill.md#initialization)):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks! # Required for proper framework handling

pod 'JumioMobileSDK', '~>2.13' # If you use BAM Checkout along Netverify in your app. Frameworks supporting device architectures only.

pod 'JumioMobileSDK/Netverify', '~>2.13' # Specify Netverify as subspec to only use Netverify, Fastfill or Document Verification
pod 'JumioMobileSDK/BAMCheckout', '~>2.13' # Specify BAMCheckout as subspec to only use BAM Checkout
```

It looks like this

```
my-plugin/
├── package.json
└── platforms/
    └── ios/
        └── Podfile
```

5- Install and Build project

```
tns plugin add ../my-plugin
tns build ios
```

It will install and build successfully but I don't know how should I use it in my project.

Any Idea?

Comment: Do you want to publish it or just use it within your project?

Comment: From that point on you need to covert the Obj-C code to JavaScript (or TypeScript depending what you prefer to work with) by following the marshalling techniques in NativeScript and the specific conversion syntax https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview

Comment: E.g. the Obj-c code `BAMCheckoutConfiguration *config = [BAMCheckoutConfiguration new];` should become `let confit = BAMCheckoutConfiguration.new() ` or  `let confit = new BAMCheckoutConfiguration() ` I think both syntax are valid in this case